# SharePoint REST API GetFileByServerRelativeUrl not working

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to fetch a file, which is downloadable in the following URL `https://notarealurl.com/sites/name/subname/My%20Folder/test.htm` with the following method:

```
fetch("/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/name/subname/My%20Folder/test.htm')/$value");
```

However it returns 404. I've tried with and without decoding the URL. Also, using the following request, doesn't return any file, just an almost empty response. Request:

```
fetch("/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/name/subname/My%20Folder')/files");
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://notarealurl.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>ab8997b7-04a9-4e43-a63f-486e9477e31b</id><title /><updated>2020-04-08T12:00:40Z</updated><author><name /></author></feed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct API URL begins from the parent directory, the correct one is:

```
fetch("/sites/name/subname/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/name/subname/My%20Folder/test.htm')/$value");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following endpoint and it works well.

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl/DocuentLibraryName/DocumentName')/$value
```

And here is one similar threads for your reference:
[How to download file from document Library using Rest Api](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7f1cb7d-4406-4b72-b7f1-dc5dde6c34e1/how-to-download-file-from-document-library-using-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Best Regards,
Baker Kong